# admob live ads not showing up after almost 4 days

Tags: admob, ads

I finished the implementation of google banner and interstitial in my app and placed my Unit IDs and the app now is released on Google Play. that was from 3.5 days ago. Since then, I only can see test ads (no live ads are displayed). So, I was wondering if I'm missing something that I should have done in Admob or in the implementation in my App?

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing test ads, it means the setup is done correctly.

Have you added testDevice like this?

```
> AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
>     .addTestDevice("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE232")
>     .build();
```

If yes, you need to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

**ADD PAYMENT INFO FROM ADMOB ACCOUNT**

if the test ads are working fine then your implementation is correct, but there is an option of "Payment"  in the admob account which you need to fill. After filling up that form you will receive an email regarding the confirmation of payment details and  message indicating that whether your information was accepted by the admob team or not if yes then your live ads will be showing up.
but keep in mind that for the first few time the ad won't show up. it takes time to appear after the approval as well.
here is the code snippet for the error code to find what is going wrong

```
mAdView = (com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

mAdView.setAdListener(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "onAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        if(errorCode==AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR)

        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "onAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "onAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "onAdLeftApplication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "onAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



    }
});

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

get the error code

```
ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR    Something happened internally; for instance, an invalid response was received from the ad server.
ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST   The ad request was invalid; for instance, the ad unit ID was incorrect.
ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR     The ad request was unsuccessful due to network connectivity.
ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL           The ad request was successful, but no ad was.
```

If you are getting error code 3 then after sometime you will get the ads  showing up after some time.